# Sort a Table based on one column, then find the next row based on 2 other Columns

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

OK guys.. I'm a little stumped on this one..

I have a table of items in locations that I am consolidating. The items are spread between different rows (like a warehouse). I have calculated what to send where, and the distance between the starting and ending position.

Now, I need to develop a report that starts with the shortest move, then from its FINISH location finds the next shortest move with a START location closest to the first moves FINISH location... so if I move obj A from warehouse row 20 to row 30, I want my next line to be the next closest move, probably in row 30, that is also the shortest distance.

```
item | start_loc | end_loc | distance
A    | 5         | 10      | 5
B    | 14        | 11      | 3
C    | 20        | 1       | 19
D    | 10        | 13      | 3
E    | 10        | 5       | 5
F    | 10        | 6       | 4
```

So the table above would be ordered

> D, B, F, A, E, C

Basically I want to optimize the amount of trips and spend the least amount of time empty handed..

Using ColdFusion and SQL to do this..

Edit from comments below:
I'll try to clarify further.. The table above would be ordered D, B, F, A, E, C because: 
D has the shortest distance - 3; 
B is the next closes to D's end (13 --> 14); 
F because move B ends at 11, 10 is the next closest row with a move, and F has the shortest move distance in that row;
A bc F ends at 6, and A starts at 5; 
E bc A ends at 10 and E starts on 10; 
C because it is the most inconvenient (longest, nothing ends by it) so it's last

**UPDATE:**
I adapted the selected answer below to work with my tables etc.. however, it is skipping one of the rows, and I'm not sure why?

```
    <!-- Add some columns to the working table for calculations -->
<cfquery name="updateWorking" datasource="planning" dbtype="obdc">

    ALTER TABLE working
    ADD move_distance FLOAT;

    ALTER TABLE working
    ADD start_loc FLOAT;

    ALTER TABLE working
    ADD finish_loc FLOAT;

    ALTER TABLE working
    ADD move_order INT;

</cfquery>
<cfquery name="updateWorking2" datasource="planning" dbtype="obdc">

    UPDATE working
    SET start_loc = LEFT(Storage_Bin, 5)
    WHERE marked_consolidate_loc IS NOT NULL;

    UPDATE working
    SET finish_loc = LEFT(marked_consolidate_loc, 5)
    WHERE marked_consolidate_loc IS NOT NULL;

    UPDATE working
    SET move_distance = finish_loc - start_loc
    WHERE marked_consolidate_loc IS NOT NULL;

    UPDATE working
    SET move_distance = ABS(move_distance)
    where move_distance < 0

</cfquery>


<!-- Query to show all the moves in order by distance, shortest first -->
<cfquery name="report" datasource="planning" dbtype="obdc">
    SELECT  id, Material, marked_consolidate, marked_consolidate_loc, marked_consolidate_su,
            max_pallet, mixed_skid, Storage_Bin, Storage_Unit, move_distance, finish_loc, start_loc
    FROM working
    WHERE marked_consolidate IS NOT NULL
    AND mixed_skid = 0
    ORDER BY move_distance ASC
</cfquery>
<!-- What is the shortest move? Do it first -->
<cfquery name="firstMove" datasource="planning" dbtype="obdc" maxRows="1">
    Select id, Material, marked_consolidate, marked_consolidate_loc, marked_consolidate_su,
            max_pallet, mixed_skid, Storage_Bin, Storage_Unit, move_distance, finish_loc, start_loc
    FROM working
    WHERE marked_consolidate IS NOT NULL
    AND mixed_skid = 0
    ORDER BY move_distance ASC, start_loc ASC
</cfquery>

<!--- set the Move Number --->
<cfset moveNumber = 1>
<!-- List to remember ID of moves that have been completed -->
<cfset tripSequence = ''>

<!-- Update the first selection as the first move -->
<cfquery name= "updateMove" datasource="planning" dbtype="obdc">
    UPDATE working
    SET move_order = #moveNumber#
    WHERE id = #firstMove.id#;
</cfquery>

<cfset moveNumber = moveNumber + 1>
<cfset tripSequence = ListAppend(tripSequence, "#firstMove.id#")>
<cfset lastMoveFinish = #firstMove.finish_loc#>

<!--- number of trips remaining --->
<cfset numberOfTrips = (report.recordCount) - 1>

<!-- Loop through the whole table -->
<cfloop from="1" to="#numberOfTrips#" index="i">
    <!--- determine next move to compare to --->
    <cfloop query="report">
        <!--- Has it been moved already?--->
        <cfif listContains(tripSequence, #report.id#)>
            <!-- If so, continue to next row -->
            <cfcontinue>
        </cfif>
        <!-- If not, remember this one -->
        <cfset nextLocationID = report.id>
        <cfset nextLocationFinishLoc = report.finish_loc>
        <cfset nextLocationDist = abs(lastMoveFinish - report.start_loc)>
    </cfloop>

    <!--- compare this move with other moves, if the next one is shorter remember it --->
    <cfloop query="report">
        <!--- Has it been moved already? --->
        <cfif listContains(tripSequence, #report.id#)>
            <cfcontinue>
        </cfif>
        <!-- How far is this move from your current location? -->
        <cfset nextLocationDistance = abs(lastMoveFinish - report.start_loc)>
        <!-- If this move is closer to you than the one you selected above, remember it instead -->
        <cfif nextLocationDistance LT nextLocationDist>
            <cfset nextLocationID = report.id>
            <cfset nextLocationFinishLoc = report.finish_loc>
            <cfset nextLocationDist = abs(lastMoveFinish - report.start_loc)>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <!-- once you have the closest move, remember it and update the column -->
    <cfset tripSequence = ListAppend(tripSequence, nextLocationID)>
    <!-- Update the move column -->
    <cfquery name= "updateMove" datasource="planning" dbtype="obdc">
        UPDATE working
        SET move_order = #moveNumber#
        WHERE id = #nextLocationID#;
    </cfquery>
    <!-- Increment the Move Number -->
    <cfset moveNumber = moveNumber + 1>

    <!--- set the ending of your last move --->
    <cfset lastMoveFinish = nextLocationFinishLoc>
</cfloop>

<!-- BELOW IS OUTPUT OF THE REPORT -->
<body>
    <!-- Build the report -->
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7">
                <h2>Consolidation Report</h2>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Move Order</td>
            <td>Current Loc</td>
            <td>Current SU</td>
            <td>Item Number</td>
            <td>Qty To Move</td>
            <td>Moved To Loc</td>
            <td>Moved To SU</td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Query to show all the moves in order by distance, shortest first -->
        <cfquery name="showReport" datasource="planning" dbtype="obdc">
                SELECT Material, marked_consolidate, marked_consolidate_loc, marked_consolidate_su,
                        Storage_Bin, Storage_Unit, move_order
                FROM working
                WHERE marked_consolidate IS NOT NULL
                AND mixed_skid = 0
                ORDER BY move_order
        </cfquery>

        <cfloop query="showReport">
            <tr>
                <cfoutput>
                    <td>#showReport.move_order#</td>
                    <td>#showReport.Storage_Bin#</td>
                    <td>#showReport.Storage_Unit#</td>
                    <td>#showReport.Material#</td>
                    <td>#showReport.marked_consolidate#</td>
                    <td>#showReport.marked_consolidate_loc#</td>
                    <td>#showReport.marked_consolidate_su#</td>
                </cfoutput>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
    </table>
    <cfoutput>#tripSequence#</cfoutput>
<body>
```

The output is a table with 49 rows.. however one of the rows Move Number is empty, and it skips Move Number: 48. Thoughts?

All rows are logically correct, it's just skipping 48 and not putting the Null row where it should be (logically would be around move 30).

Comment: You should always try to include your database rdbms

Comment: Beside `order by distance` I'm not sure what are you asking.

Comment: I think you'd need to do this inside a loop.  Grab the closest item and put it in order until there are no more items left.  If there are relatively few records (hundreds or a few thousands) a QofQ might be easiest.

Comment: I'll try to clarify further..
The table above would be ordered D, B, F, A, E, C because:
D has the shortest distance - 3; 
B is the next closes to D's end (13 --> 14); 
F because move B ends at 11, 10 is the next closest row with a move, and F has the shortest move distance in that row; 
A bc F ends at 6, and A starts at 5; 
E bc A ends at 10 and E starts on 10; 
C because it is the most inconvenient (longest, nothing ends by it) so it's last

Comment: I think I will need a loop or QofQ, we are only dealing with a couple hundred rows...

Comment: You're right, but the implementation will depend on the RDBMS. Is this SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL? Something else?

Comment: I apologize - it's SQL Server 2012

Comment: D and B both have a distance of 3.  Why does D have to be first?

Comment: In this example it doesn't have to be, I suppose it could have went B then D. The idea is that it will always find the next start_loc closest to your finish_loc, and if there are multiple of the same start_loc then select the one with the shortest distance to it's finish_loc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tackling the TSP, eh? That's my solution for you and unless you run thousands of nodes, it should be fine performance wise.

```
<cfset data = queryNew(
    "item,start_loc,end_loc,distance",
    "VARCHAR,INTEGER,INTEGER,INTEGER",
    [
        [ "A", 5, 10, 5 ],
        [ "B", 14, 11, 3 ],
        [ "C", 20, 1, 19 ],
        [ "D", 10, 13, 3 ],
        [ "E", 10, 5, 5 ],
        [ "F", 10, 6, 4 ]
    ]
)>

<cfset tripSequence = []>

<!--- BEGIN: determine first item --->

    <cfquery name="closestLocation" dbType="query" maxRows="1">

        SELECT
            *

        FROM
            [data]

        ORDER BY
            [distance] ASC,
            [start_loc] ASC

    </cfquery>

    <!--- add item --->
    <cfset tripSequence.add(closestLocation.item)>

<!--- END: determine first item --->

<!--- number of trips remaining --->
<cfset numberOfTrips = (data.recordCount - 1)>

<cfloop from="1" to="#numberOfTrips#" index="i">

    <!--- BEGIN: determine next trip to compare to --->

        <cfloop query="data">

            <!--- must not have been done already --->
            <cfif arrayFind(tripSequence, data.item)>
                <cfcontinue>
            </cfif>

            <cfset nextLocation = {
                item:       data.item,
                end_loc:    data.end_loc,
                distance:   abs(closestLocation.end_loc - data.start_loc)
            }>

        </cfloop>

    <!--- END: determine next trip to compare to --->

    <!--- BEGIN: compare with remaining trips --->

        <cfloop query="data">

            <!--- must not have been done already --->
            <cfif arrayFind(tripSequence, data.item)>
                <cfcontinue>
            </cfif>

            <cfset nextLocationDistance = abs(closestLocation.end_loc - data.start_loc)>

            <cfif nextLocationDistance lt nextLocation.distance>

                <cfset nextLocation = {
                    item:       data.item,
                    end_loc:    data.end_loc,
                    distance:   nextLocationDistance
                }>

            </cfif>

        </cfloop>

    <!--- END: compare with remaining trips --->

    <!--- add item --->
    <cfset tripSequence.add(nextLocation.item)>

    <!--- take item as base for the next iteration --->
    <cfset closestLocation = nextLocation>

</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#arrayToList(tripSequence, ", ")#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very elegant solution. I was previously attempting with cfloops and attempting to remember, but was getting stuck because I wasn't calculating the distance for each move from the current location.

Comment: Alexander - I have adapted what you have above, and it is working great, except one thing! I have 49 rows in my test table, and for some reason one of them is being skipped. It is not added to the tripSequence. I added a column to my table and update the column with the 'move_number' when I add to the tripSequence. With 49 rows and looping 49 times it numbers everything 1-49, skipping number 48, and leaving one value null. Based on looking at the data, the row that is left null should have been used around move 30. Any ideas?
Updated my question above with current code..

Answer (score 0):

Fun question, sql and a logic puzzle. Obviously a job for recursion, went with a while loop to keep it simple:

```
create table #examplework (item varchar(1), start_Loc int, end_loc int, distance int)

insert into #examplework
select 'a', 5, 10, 5
union
select 'b', 14, 11, 3
union
select 'c', 20, 1, 19
union
select 'd', 10, 13, 3
union
select 'e', 10, 5, 5
union
select 'f', 10, 6, 4

create table #worktable (Workingpath varchar(900), Current_Step varchar(1))
declare @step varchar(1) = (select top 1 item from #examplework order by distance) 
declare @path varchar(900) = ''

while @step is not null
begin
insert into #worktable
select concat(@path, ',' , @step) as Workingpath, @step as CurrentStep

set @step = (select top 1 ew1.item 
             from #examplework ew
             join #examplework ew1 on ew.item != ew1.item
             where ew.item = @step
             and ew1.item not in (select Current_Step from #worktable)
             order by abs(ew.end_loc - ew1.start_Loc))
set @path = (select top 1 Workingpath from #worktable order by len(Workingpath) desc)

end

select top 1 * from #worktable
order by LEN(workingpath) desc
```

Thus the salesman paradox is solved in sql again (darn college homework). To step through it, I set the step variable, then grab the closest item that does not appear in the work table. Once all items are in the work table the while loop closes. Hope that helps.

*edit* whoops if this is the TSP, you can't simply pick a node and hope the nearest leads to the best route. You need to brute force the hell out of it, look at all possible combinations and pick the one that requires the least travel. Here is an example of that:

```
select CONCAT(a.item, ',', b.item, ',', c.item, ',', d.item, ',', e.item, ',', f.item) as route,
sum(abs(a.end_loc - b.start_Loc) + abs(b.end_loc - c.start_Loc) + abs(c.end_loc - d.start_Loc) + ABS(d.end_loc - e.start_Loc) + abs(e.end_loc - f.start_Loc)) as distance  
from
#examplework a
join #examplework b on b.item != a.item
join #examplework c on c.item != a.item and c.item != b.item
join #examplework d on d.item != a.item and d.item != b.item and d.item != c.item
join #examplework e on e.item != a.item and e.item != b.item and e.item != c.item and e.item != d.item
join #examplework f on f.item != a.item and f.item != b.item and f.item != c.item and f.item != d.item and f.item != e.item
group by CONCAT(a.item, ',', b.item, ',', c.item, ',', d.item, ',', e.item, ',', f.item)
order by distance
```

That is literally the only way to solve the TSP, the other method will get you a good route, the brute force method will get you the best route.

Comment: Thank you for the example! Although I went with the other provided example since I am working with both coldfusion and SQL, and the others in my area are more familiar with cf than SQL. Keeping it more cf will help with maintenance later. And although I am in college, this is actually solving a real-world problem we have at my current job.